# Sorting after displaying deep JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, sorting

I have a dynamic JSON object that has multi-level depth to support a folder structure.

The object is being stored in a state, looking similar to this:

```
 {
      "_contents": [
        {
          "name": "filename_1",
          "path": "filename_1"
        },
        {
          "name": "filename_2",
          "path": "filename_2"
        }
      ],
      "folder_1": {
        "_contents": [
          {
            "name": "filename_1",
            "path": "folder_1/filename_1"
          },
          {
            "name": "filename sdafasdfasdfs",
            "path": "sasfasdfas"
          }
        ]
      },
      "folder_2": {
        "_contents": [],
        "folder_2_1": {
          "_contents": [
            {
              "name": "filename1.md",
              "path": "folder_2/folder_2_1/filename1.md"
            }
          ],
          "folder_2_1_1": {
            "_contents": [
              {
                "name": "filename1.md",
                "path": "folder_2/folder_2_1/folder_2_1_1/filename1.md"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I then pass my object into a react component that generate a UI folder view.
Using this module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nested-file-tree

The issue I'm running into is that after I pass my object state into the node component, the order of the files are being lost.

They go in `1, 2, 3` and come out in the UI as `2,3,1` (or some other random order).

This seems to be a problem in general with mapping through deep JSON objects. But I haven't found a way to prevent or change this?

Is there any way I can preserve the order of my JSON object, or sort after the UI has been built? I've looked into other modules that generate UI's, and I'm getting similar results.

EDIT: I should note that I'm restricted to building my JSON object to fit into the format of whatever module I'm using.

Comment: @canon care to expand on that point?

Comment: @canon The JSON object is being generated dynamically based on a shared dropbox folder. So after the object is created, no it does not change until the next time a new file/folder is added.

Comment: @canon It's with the order of the property names. `folder_1`, `folder_2`. Ideally the `_contents` should retain order as well, but I'm willing to compromise on that for now.

Comment: @canon I understand that they don't retain order. I'm trying to find a way after the fact that they are passed into the component to order them.

Comment: My mistake, @23k.

Comment: JSON is a string format. So you have an object, not a JSON object. Besides that, you would have to alter the module. Asking us to go digging into the module's code seems to be a tall order. Might want to add an issue to that module's GitHub page or whatever... and it seems [someone already did](https://github.com/woodpig07/react-nested-file-tree/issues/1).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm the one that opened the issue ha. I was mostly just curious if someone has run into a similar issue already with this specific module or another that does the same thing.